# Spring - Stop redirection on error

Tags: spring, error-handling

I have a page to manage users and I would like to stay on the page if any error occurs when clicking save.
The only cases I found online where to do with validation.

Also my page requires the userId to be posted so I don't think returning the name of the original page in the controller would work. Also I would loose the changes made in the page.

What I am trying to achieve is stay in the same page, showing a message to the user.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, final Map<String, Object> model) {

    User user = spiService.getUser(userId);
    model.put("user", user);

    configureRoles(model, user);

    return "edituser";
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUser(@RequestParam("userJson") String userRoles, @RequestParam("userId") String userId, final Map<String, Object> model) throws IOException {

    User user = spiService.getUser(userId);

    try { 
        addRoles(JsonUtil.getField(userRoles, "addedRoles"), user.getRoles(), userId);
        removeRoles(JsonUtil.getField(userRoles, "removedRoles"), user.getRoles(), userId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // What now?
    }

    return "users";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting you can use Ajax calls in your controller. For that you have to create one AjaxPojoClass  for example`AjaxResponseBody` as your convenience.
For example

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "/yourUrl",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        window.location.replace("/successUrl")
    },
    error : function(e) {
        display(e);
    },
});
```

AjaxController

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/yourUrl")
    public AjaxResponseBody getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody SearchCriteria search) {

        AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();
        //logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I could use Ajax, I am already using it for other stuff, but I want the app to redirect to a success page if everything goes OK

Comment: Simply for success response you can also redirect app from ajax call using `window.location.replace("/successUrl")`

Comment: Does it make sense?

Answer (score -1):

you can use ajax to submit your request.

Comment: Can you elaborate?